# File conversion canary

Tags: linux, windows, clipboard, conversion

Is there a way to tell if a flat ASCII log file, eg. the output of a command, was converted to an office document (typically: Word, Excel, Notepad) and back to a flat text file?

I know at least one of my users is doing this when inspecting the contents of files before they send it out and I noticed it because text after a tab character went missing when the text was copied to and from a spreadsheet. I think it is simply happening because people are unaware of details changing in conversion as they only have their regular office tools at hand, and the end result does look identical ...

Now what I have thought of myself so far is:

1. Insert a TAB character, when copying to a spreadsheet the tab will move to the next cell. Then when selecting the first column, some of the text will go missing. (This is how I found out it is happening).
2. Insert a `=1/0` which will change into a `#DIV/0` in a spreadsheet and when copied back the string error message will be present rather than the formula.
3. Of course a swapped CR/LF is a dead giveway.

Anyway, can someone come up with a small and smart text string that can be used as an indicator that the file has been converted to an office document? Bonus if it can be used in a `HERE document` in a `bash` script. That way at least I am aware that it happened and the file contents may have changed on the way from the Linux box into my mailbox. Obscurity has no place, there is no need for me to hide this canary.

Comment: Can you come up with a validity tester: test that the document is valid, according to the grammar (this depends on your use-case).